# Compiling Test classes:not working

Tags: maven-2

I wanted to package the class files under target/test-classes(ie src/test/java) as one assembly.
When I am running the maven command,i am getting the error:
Reason: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive : You must set at least one file.

My assembly desciptor is :

```
  <assembly>

<id>stress-client</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}
        </directory>
        <includes>

            list of files to be included


        </includes>


        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>

    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

i find test-classes empty.Why the test files are not getting compiled?
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the assembly is trying to run before the `test-compile` phase, in which case there will be no classes to include. Or you are running `mvn assembly:assembly`, in which case the default lifecycle will not be run and the test classes not compiled. You could bind the execution of the assembly plugin to a later phase (e.g. `package`) to ensure the processing is completed before the assembly is constructed.

However you don't need to use an assembly to package test-classes. This can be done by configuring the jar plugin to package the [test jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html) as follows:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

By default the test jar will be attached to the project, and when installed/deployed will have the classifier `tests`.

If you must use the assembly, here is how you bind it to the default lifecycle so that it will be run when package is called.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>src/main/assembly/test-assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-test-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

If this still does not work, it suggests you are using a non-standard packaging type that doesn't perform the relevant goals for test processing, or your test sources are defined in a non-standard location so they are not being processed. If you are still having trouble can you append the output from your build to your question?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.The requirement is to create an assembly.
I even tried explicitly given the configuration as "test-compile package " [while using eclipse plugin].But still no classes for Test

Comment: Hurray..it worked...
I found something strange also..
I have given the final name of the assembly as XX...but the assembly that is getting created has the name as per the format artifactID-version.jar..
Why is this so?

Comment: The finalName is only applied for the jar when output to the target location, when it is installed/deployed it will be attached with a classifier that defaults to the assembly's id. This can't be overridden and is really needed so Maven can follow the conventions

Comment: ...and glad to help. If you found this answer addressed your problem, you can choose to accept it

Comment: Hi
 Can you pls clarify the point wrt-defaults to assembly id.
Let me tell you in detail whats happening in my proj.
I m creating many assemblies(4-5),output to target.1/2of these are not taking their final names(or assembly id) , but as per the format artifactID-version.jar..This is very confusing

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is that the pom does not have packaging **pom**. If packaging is pom the test compilation will not be triggered.